# one connection to database and big data or more connection and small data?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have tow tables (person and profile).I created view and i want to show information to GridView

Two solutions:
1 - By one query throw big data to DataSet and bind it to GridView
2 - Create a class for *peson* by constructor  and for each person get information and add to list and bind it to GridView

Which way is faster , standard , ... ?

Comment: It would be personal opinion to give any *general* suggestion. It depends on many things. Getting only person list (solution 2) or populating `DataSet` manually could be very good if you want more control over the process and to save memory (virtual lists). Reading whole database (solution 1) could be awkward idea (memory-wise), but in certain scenarios (when you know for sure what data returned by query will be not big) reading everything and then performing operation without database connection is pretty ok.

Answer (score 0):

First if data is only for reading then instead of DataSet use [DataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

and surely if not required why to pull all data at once, use the 2nd approach.